# A body which lists the Artists with the most songs in order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a ruby on rails program which consists of two databases

Parent Table

```
CreateArtists < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table :artists do |t|
    t.string :name, null: false
    t.integer :age, null: false

    t.string :nationality, null: false

    t.timestamps null: false
   end
  end
end
```

Child Table

```
CreateSingles < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
     create_table :singles do |t|
     t.belongs_to :artist, index: true, foreign_key: true
     t.string :title, null: false
     t.integer :year, null: false

     t.timestamps null: false
     end
   end
  end`
```

At the moment i'm current displaying the Artists but want them in descending order of who has the most songs

```
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Nationality</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <% @artists.each do |artist| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= artist.name %></td>
    <td><%= artist.age %></td>
    <td><%= artist.nationality %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I know i could use a counter cache to determine which artist has the most songs but i want to use a query

I know i need to change

```
@artists.each do |artist|
```

Any thoughts?

Also this is my first time posting on stack overflow so apologies for the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with:

```
Artist.joins(:singles)
      .group(:id)
      .order('count(artists.id) DESC')
```

Comment: I had that but without the "count part" thank you very much!